# Is an extra port opened when accessing localhost:port?

Tags: networking

Imagine a program serves "Hello World" on localhost port 6000.

If I visit localhost:6000 in Chrome, is an intermediate port opened to send back the response? From the POV of the server, the request must have a source IP and port so it can send back the response. Is this an intermediate port say 5000 which Chrome listens to for a response?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/server are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP clients use an *ephemeral port* for outgoing connections, allocated from the OS stack.

"Open a port" usually refers to opening an incoming and listening port on a firewall, with destination NAT or similar.

That is not the case here as the client's outgoing, ephemeral port can only be used for that connection (socket), ie. from the other side's TCP port it is connected with. Ports accepting arbitrary connections need to be in the *listening* state, usually set by the server application.

Of course, all *localhost* connections are local to that specific host only. They cannot be used from the outside network in any case.

Comment: That's a fair distinction but in localhost will a port be ephemerally allocated the same way by the OS stack? Or does localhost have some special shortcut?

Comment: Allocating an ephemeral port works the exact same way with the localhost loopback. However, the loopback (a kind of shortcut) is just a virtual interface where the packets never leave the local stack.